# Text of ListView Subitems not updated when using AddRange (WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

After updating the texts of sub items for a ListView item the new texts are not displayed in the ListView.
Invalidating, Updating, Redrawing, Refreshing are not helping.

I used AddRange to add the sub items.

What can I do to reflect the changes on the UI?

Comment: Is datasource assigned to listview?

Answer (score 0):

As [KevinBui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836376/kevinbui) pointed out in [this article "C# setting ListView's Item's Subitem's text does not display"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785580/c-sharp-setting-listviews-items-subitems-text-does-not-display) new sub item texts are not displayed in the ListView when [ListView.AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1c1wawcw(v=vs.110).aspx)  was used to add the sub items due to a bug in the .NET Framework.

Don't use AddRange but [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead.